# UV texture not applied

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I downloaded a character from [here](http://static.biligame.com/caster_custom_assets/ys/gczj/ying.rar) and opened it using CATS addon. Face was pink, indicating missing texture. However, I confirmed, that the texture was indeed not missing.

The texture appears correctly in "Texture Paint" layout, but not in any other tabs.

Any idea what's causing this?

[image: layout tab]

[image: texture paint tab]

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

Texture is there, but in that quite complex material toon01.bmp and toon02.bmp texture is still missing.

Those textures are used to overlay MMD base texture node. So the results appears pink.

BTW would be helpful to mentioned version of your Blender. Written for 2.7, 2.8, works for me under 2.91, but errors for 3.+ ... took me a time to figure out what cause the issue.

### Solution

I never deal with toon shaders so I'm just guessing ... according to packed toon.png texture and this reference ...

[image]

... you are missing the skin texture. So I just took bluish (toon.png) texture, edited color in some image editor app by shifting HUE value to get some skin tone (Saturate, Brighter) and saved as missing texture "toon.02.bmp".

[image]

Update source under Material editor the Image node properties ...

[image]

Comment: So is there a way to fix that if toon1 and toon2 bmp files are missing?
Thanks for the reply tho!

Comment: Answer updated ...